# Create static content with images and videos and show it in my spring-boot application

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, static-site

I wrote some basic blog system, which based on spring boot.
I'm trying to figure out, how can I create posts with videos and images, without the need to editing everything using HTML.

Right now, I am saving my blog posts in DB as plain text.
Is it possible to create content combined with text, images and videos , and saving this "content" as one row in my DB-Table, without creating connections between different tables?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Do your blog posts have a standard format?  With images and videos in the same place everytime?  Or is each blog post a variable format and can have any number of images and videos?

Answer (score 0):

Images and Videos are heavy content and storing them in database could be a costly affair, until you are developing application for research purpose. Also querying it from database and serving it over the network can impact your application performance.

If you want to store it in a single row that can be done as well using database BLOB object. But i would suggest to have 2 different tables. One containing the BLOB object of Image and Videos and other is your usual table containing blog as text and primary key of of BLOB table.

If you want to take your solution to go live, better use image-videos hosting servers because of following factors

1. Saves your database cost
2. Ensures 24x7 availability
3. Application performance is faster as these are hosted independent of application
4. Videos can directly be iframed i.e. you do not need to query complete MBs of record and serve over network

Answer (score 0):

A strict answer to your question, yes, you can use BLOBs to store the video/images in the database. Think about them as a column that contains bytes of video or image.

For school/cases where you have a very small amount of videos/images its probably OK. However if you're building a real application, then don't do it :)

Every DBA will raise a bunch of concerns "why do not use Blobs".

So more realistic approach would be to find some "file-system" like storage (but distributed) style S3 in AWS, hardrive on server if you're not on cloud, etc.

Then store that big image / video there and get an identifier (like path to it if we're talking about the harddrive) and store that identifier in the database along with the metadata that you're already store probably (like blogPostId, type of file, etc.)

Once the application become more "mature" - you can switch the "provider" - Grow as you go. There are even cloud storages designed especially for images (like Cloudinary).